# Learnstreet java lesson 3 part 8, reversing a string

Tags: java, string

question asks to reverse characters "mug" set as a string into "gum"
I tried the suggested

```
"mug".charAt(2) + "mug".charAt(1) + "mug".charAt(0)
```

once input it says incorrect

Comment: Well that is interesting. Why are you telling us this?

Comment: Please clarify, is this question about Java, as the title suggests, or JavaScript as the tags suggest?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two **very** different languages, make sure you know which one you are asking about if you want to get useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"mug".charAt(2) +""+ "mug".charAt(1) +""+ "mug".charAt(0);
```

Or

```
""+ "mug".charAt(2) + "mug".charAt(1) + "mug".charAt(0);
```

You current code will give you output as `329`. Because of `+` operator.

Or try this:

```
String str="";
char arr[] = "mug".toCharArray();
for(int i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    str += arr[i];
}
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code results an integer `329`, the result of char plus char is integer.

To reverse a string,  you may use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` 's `reverse` method:

```
new StringBuilder("mug").reverse().toString()
```

or

```
new StringBuffer("mug").reverse().toString()
```